# I have to start Prettier each time manually as it doesn't start automatically

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

```js
{
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
    },
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai Pro",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vs-seti",
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modifications",
    "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,
    "prettier.arrowParens": "avoid",
    "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

[image: Prettier at the right bottom without]

Default Formatter: esbenp.prettier-vscode
Format on save: clicked
View/Command Palette/Format Document With/ Prettier Code Formatter (default)

Even though I have done the proper settings as above, I have to start prettier each time when I opened vscode. CTRL+S doesnt trigger prettier  at first. As soon as I set <View/Command Palette/Format Document With/ Prettier Code Formatter (default)> it starts working.
Do you know what the problem would be with it?

Comment: Can you provide the `settings.json` part where is set those configurations that you mention?

Comment: Do you know where this JSON file is?

Comment: Under settings, on the top right corner, you'll see an icon which looks like a file

Comment: If you change `"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modifications"` to `"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file"` does it work? It'll format the entire file, but to check if the formatting works would be ok.

Comment: I have tried, it didnt work.